# Deleting all nodes NeojClient

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I have tried running this query:

```
var query = clientConnection.Cypher
                    .Start(new
                    {
                        n = "node(*)"
                    })
                    .Delete("n");
```

And when I check the web console the nodes are still there?
What am I missing?

Comment: Unrelated, but you can use Start(new { n = All.Nodes })

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did. I used Pangeas query and added in the `.ExecuteWithoutResults();` as well as Tathams `.Start(new { n = All.Nodes })`

```
clientConnection.Cypher
                .Start(new { n = All.Nodes })
                .Match("(n)-[r?]-(x)")
                .With("n, r")
                .Delete("n, r")
                .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Now all nodes are deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below cypher to delete all nodes and relationships

```
START n=node(*) 
MATCH n-[r?]-m 
WITH n, r 
DELETE n, r
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this query

To delete all nodes don't have relatioships
START n=node(*)
delete n

If there are relationships for the nodes
START n=node(*)
MATCH n-[r]->(x)
DELETE r,n

Comment: well what if you dont know the direction of the relationships? I would rather do `match (n)-[r]-(x)`